# Probability of partial collision

Tags: combinatorics, statistics

I know that this has to be strongly related to the Birthday problem, but my statistics skills are getting a bit rusty, and I couldn't find a question dealing with this special case here with the search terms I used, so apologies if I overlooked something.

My generalized question is as follows:

> Given a finite set $S$ of $k$-digit numeric values with uniformly distributed digits, how likely is it that among $n$ randomly chosen values from this set I find at least two values that are considered the same if only the same sub-representation amounting to $q$ percent of their full representation is looked at?

An example: Say, I draw a sample of $n$ numbers in the range from 0(000) to 9999 (i.e. $k=4$ decimal digits), but only compare the middle two digits ($q=50$%) of them, how likely am I to obtain a collision?

Obviously, in the case of $q=100$% this is equivalent to the classical birthday problem, and the reduced amount of required overlap will definitely make collisions more likely the lower this required overlap is assumed to be. I am, however, not sure about *how* it scales.

*Note:* Eventually, I am looking for a solution closer to the example, where there is a finite digital representation of numbers that may exhibit collisions in their partial numerical representation, but I would also be interested in knowing whether a generalised solution (basically assuming very large $k$) exists and how $q$ would come into play there.

Comment: I suppose the 'uniformly distributed numeric values' can only take values from a finite set (say, positive integers less than some $k$)?

Comment: Are you interested in comparing specific digits (middle two) or in a fraction of their representation (two of the four digits, regardless of their position)? They are not the same.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri If I get your question correctly, I want to compare the same partial representation in all samples (i.e. each one's middle two digits, and not any two digits of each sample)

Comment: I think the range of numbers you're considering will matter. For example, 8000-8009 will have 100% chance while 8000-8100 will not.

Comment: @FullofDill valid concern. We may assume that all given digits will be uniformly distributed, i.e. only number ranges from 0 to an arbitrary string of 9s (or whatever the largest digit in the number system you are using is. In a binary world, this would obviously be 1, in hexadecimal F)

Comment: Hopefully this gives you an idea how to proceed. Assume the numbers have $d$ digits (those with less than $d$ digits will use 0's as fillers, i.e. 0000 instead of 0). Start by looking at the probability of two numbers having the specified digits in common and give the number of these digits the label $q$. Given an arbitrary first number, the probability that the second number has the specified digits in common is $\frac{10^{d-q}}{10^d}$. The numerator is the number of possible numbers with q digits fixed. The denominator is the unrestricted number of possible numbers...

Comment: ...Note that this assumes it's legal for other digits in the two numbers to be identical. If you want only those two specific digits in common then the probability is $\frac{9^{d-q}}{10^d}$ since one digit will be illegal in each of the other spots. Now you know the probability of two numbers having those digits in common, I think you can calculate the probability of at least 2 of the $n$ numbers.

Comment: Are numbers padded with leading $0$'s? For instance, do we consider $0$ to be $0000$, and hence do we consider that its middle two digits do collide with, say, $1001$?

Comment: yes, that may be assumed for simplicity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the following (based on the comment section of the opening question):

- Numbers are 'drawn with replacement' and uniformly (as in the birthday problem)
- Any digit can take any value between $0$ and $9$, inclusive
- Numbers are padded with leading $0$'s where applicable

Under these assumptions, sampling a number with $k$ digits is the same as sampling $k$ digits independently $($from $0$ to $9)$.
Moreover, there's another assumption:

- Position of matching digits matters

This means that for our purposes, sampling a number with $k$ digits, $q$ digits of which we are interested in, is the same as sampling a number of $q$ digits, which as noted above is the same as sampling $q$ digits independently.
Therefore:

> Sampling $n$ numbers with $k$ digits such that, for each of them, we are only interested in $q$ digit positions, is the same as sampling $q$ digits independently $n$ times.

Can you see how this reduces the question to the birthday problem?

Comment: Hm, this implies that the relative sizes of the two sampling spaces is not of any relevance, i.e. only the absolute amount of digits compared matters. Even though this makes a lot of sense, it somehow still surprises me.